# IPFS as window service (win 7)

Tags: service, window, ipfs

Trying to add "IPFS daemon" as a window service.

Here is what i tried:

SC command:

```
sc.exe create IPFS binpath= "\"C:\Program Files\go-ipfs\ipfs.exe\" \"daemon\"" DisplayName= "IPFS" start= "auto"
```

Output:

```
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

The "path to execute" in service.msc reflects as:

```
"C:\Program Files\go-ipfs\ipfs.exe" "daemon"
```

This path is correct and runs the IPFS daemon if i type in cmd.

But when i start the service with "NET START IPFS" it says

```
The service is not responding to the control function.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use ipfs.exe directly as a windows service, but this is not supported by ipfs.exe. It is just a normal windows executable.

I think you will have to use a service wrapper tool such as https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw to wrap the ipfs binary as a windows service.